# Pass user-defined arraylist jsp/jstl

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am passing the following array list to jsp.

```
class A{
    String a;
    String b
}
```

In the main servlet,

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    A a = new A("Hello", "World");
    A a2 = new A("Welcome","India");
    List<A> val = new List<A>;
    val.add(a);
    val.add(a2);
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("values", values);
    response.sendRedirect("./B.jsp");
}
```

Now in jsp, can anyone please suggest how to get the list and display them as table entries. I have tried the following.

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<% List<A> lst = (List<A>) session.getAttribute("values"); %>
```

But getting, A cannot be resolved to a type in jsp. Please help how to display this as table entries and oblige.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add an import for class A on the jsp, similar to the import used for java.util.List

```
 <%@page import="package.A"%>
```

EDIT:

Here is how you can do it:

```
     <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.values}" var="current">
         <tr>
          <td><c:out value="${current.a}" /><td>
         <td><c:out value="${current.b}" /><td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```

You have set the list in the variable "values" in the session. That can be accessed from the JSP by using the expression ${sessionScope.values}.

And add this at the top of the page. It will refer to the standard JSTL tags:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

More info can be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0380__JSTL/UseForEachtoLoopThroughArrayList.htm)

Comment: Thanks, can you please suggest how to use the list entries, like how to access a and b values of each entry of the list?